# Months in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date

I have an array of dates ['1/7/1993';'4/21/1993';'6/11/1993';'2/7/1994';'5/26/1994';'3/15/1995'], and want to covert it into an array of dates with format 'mm/yyyy' with all the months and years within the minimum and maximum date included, i.e. datr = ['1/1993';'2/1993';'3/1993';.......;'3/1995']

How can I do it? Also how do I calculate the no. of months between two dates in Matlab?

Answer (score 5):

First, I hope I'm not assuming too much here but MATLAB has built in [Date and Time Operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-42340.html#f16-32430) that if you aren't already using, you should start using.

There are three ways to represent dates (as straight from the doc)

```
Date String:           '24-Oct-2003 12:45:07'
Date Vector:           [2003  10  24  12  45  07]
Serial Date Number:    7.3188e+005
```

There is a function called [`datevec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html), and if you can get your dates into this Date Vector format then it is easy to compute the number of months between two dates:

```
date1 = datevec('17-jun-04', 'dd-mmm-yy')
date2 = datevec('24-oct-03', 'dd-mmm-yy')

% This if/else checks which date is later than the other
if(datenum(date1) > datenum(date2))
    % num months is the number of months left in date2's year (ex. 2 months)+
    % the number of months in date1's year (ex. 6 months) +
    % the number of months in the years between (ex. 0 months).
    num_months = (12 - date2(2)) +  date1(2) + 12*(date1(1)-date2(1)-1)
else
    %just flipped date1 and date2 from the above.
    num_months = (12 - date1(2)) + date2(2) + 12*(date2(1)-date1(2)-1) 
end
```

The above code uses [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) to check if date1 is greater than date2 (or vice versa)

Also, if you want to display just the month and years, you can specify how to display a date string with [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html)

```
>> date1

date1 =

        2004           6          17           0           0           0



>> datestr(date1,'mm/yyyy') %Displays just month and year

ans =

06/2004
```